# Where to host SSL certs on ec2 node.js server

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am a newbie to dev ops and EC2. I am running a nod server on AWS EC2, but I need to make it use https. I have all the material to create the cert and add it to my node.js server.

This may seem like a silly question, but where do I host the cert? Can it be hosted on S3? I don't use Elastic Cloud or CloudFront so need to manage it myself.

```
var key = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../cert/key.pem'));
var cert = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../cert/cert.pem'));
var ca = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../cert/cai.pem'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using CloudFront infront of NodeJS EC2 instance, which will also cache the static content at the edge locations. You can add your own SSL certificate to AWS certificate manager(Or use AWS issued free SSL certificates) and link it with the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: So our node server is for socket connections. How will cloudfront effect this? Specifically, we are running KUE server.

Comment: Oh not for web? Then you can use a ALB which also can assign certificate there.

Comment: I found mongoose having issues with Lambda but mongodb worked for me so far. I havent tried with the latest version though. Can you also verify local and Lambda, Node platform versions are similar.